# Coercing NAs, NaNs or 0 in xls using R package xlsx

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to read "one" column from a multi-column .xls file using the `read.xlsx()` function. It is returning a `data.frame` with 29 obs and 1 variable (in which the observations lies) even if I read through the 42 rows with blanks I want to coerce the blanks in NAs, NaNs or 0. Can someone please help me with that? For example:

```
require(xlsx)
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b) 
write.xlsx(df, "df.xls")
req_column = read.xlsx ("df.xls", sheetIndex=1, colIndex= 2, startRow=1, endRow= 10,
                        as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE,colClasses="character")
```

gives the column with 3 obs and 1 variable, but I want 10 observations with NA, NANs or 0 in the blank columns instead.

Comment: Did you use fill = TRUE? Also from the package: _endRow: a number specifying the index of the last row to pull. If NULL, read all the rows
in the sheet. For read.xlsx this argument is active only if rowIndex is NULL_

Comment: yes i just tried fill = TRUE and run the code again with rowIndex= NULL but still not working. Nikul